# Flume NG not writing to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I'm new at using Flume and Hadoop so I'm trying to setup the simplest (but somewhat helpful/realistic) example I can. I'm using the [HortonWorks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/) in a VM client. After following one tutorial 12 (which involves setting up and using Flume) everything seems to be working correctly.

So I setup my own flume.conf that should

- Read from an apache access log
- Use a memory channel
- Write to the HDFS

Simple enough right? Here's my conf file

```
agent.sources=exec-source
agent.sinks=hdfs-sink
agent.channels=ch1

agent.sources.exec-source.type=exec
agent.sources.exec-source.command=tail -F /var/log/httpd/access_log

agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type=hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path=/flume/events
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.filePrefix=apacheaccess
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval=10
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollSize=0

agent.channels.ch1.type=memory
agent.channels.ch1.capacity=1000

agent.sources.exec-source.channels=ch1
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel=ch1
```

I've seen several people have problems writing to HDFS, and in most cases it was that there weren't enough logs to fill the HDFS block. However, rollInterval=10 should generate a new file every 10 seconds, as long as at least 1 line is written to it. I can run "tail -F /var/log/httpd/access_log" in another window and see lines being written to the log fairly consistantly, so I don't think it's that.

and here's the command/output from trying to start this agent

```
[root@sandbox ~]# flume-ng agent -f /etc/flume/conf/flume.conf -n apache-agent
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Including HBASE libraries found via (/usr/bin/hbase) for HBASE access
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar from classpath
+ exec /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31//bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/usr/lib/flume/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../conf:/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/..:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/ambari-log4j-1.2.3.7.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-lzo-0.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/..:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.94.6.1.3.0.0-107-security.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.94.6.1.3.0.0-107-security-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-1.5.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/junit-4.10-HBASE-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/zookeeper.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop/build.xml:/usr/lib/hadoop/CHANGES.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/contrib:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-ant-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-ant.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-client-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-client.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-minicluster-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-minicluster.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-test-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-test.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-tools-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/HDP-CHANGES.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/ivy:/usr/lib/hadoop/ivy.xml:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec:/usr/lib/hadoop/LICENSE.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/logs:/usr/lib/hadoop/LONGWING-CHANGES.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/NOTICE.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/pids:/usr/lib/hadoop/README.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/sbin:/usr/lib/hadoop/webapps:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/ambari-log4j-1.2.3.7.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.LICENSE.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jdiff:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-2.1:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.2.LICENSE.txt:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*plugin*jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin:/usr/lib/zookeeper/conf:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/ant-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/ant-launcher-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/httpcore-4.2.3.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/jsoup-1.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-model-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-profile-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-project-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-repository-metadata-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-file-1.0-beta-6.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-http-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-6.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-http-shared4-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../conf:/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/..:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/ambari-log4j-1.2.3.7.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-lzo-0.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/conf' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 org.apache.flume.node.Application -f /etc/flume/conf/flume.conf -n apache-agent
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:/etc/flume/conf/flume.conf
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: hdfs-sink Agent: agent
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent]
13/09/03 12:35:11 WARN node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: No configuration found for this host:apache-agent
13/09/03 12:35:11 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
```

Now at this point I realize I'm missing several things.

```
1) I expect to see something along the lines of "INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: hdfs-sink started" as my last line, which I don't
2) If I use the command “hadoop fs -lsr /flume” I should see new logs in my HDFS, but I don't. The last logs are from 8/28/2013, when I did the tutorial.
```

I also don't expect to see that WARN line in there, but I'm not sure why it's there, so maybe that's my problem and someone can tell me why.

So my questions are:

```
1) Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong here?
2) When I get this problem sorted out, is there anything else I should be looking for to see what Flume is working correctly, reading what it should and writing to where it should and when?
```

Comment: Try adding --conf <conf>, where conf = configuration directory and where flume-env.sh and other flume related config files reside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is, of course, to name your agent when you start flume the same as your agent name in the config file. So my command line should have ended "-n agent" and NOT "-n apache-agent" since my flume.conf file specifies "agent.X"

After that everything appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

In the config file you specified

```
agent.sources=exec-source
agent.sinks=hdfs-sink
agent.channels=ch1
```

so the agent name is 'agent' flume expects that while running the flume-agent you should use the same name as specified in the config file so the command should be

```
/usr/lib/flume/bin/flume-ng agent -n agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do [set the agent in step #3](https://github.com/romainr/cdh-twitter-example#configuring-flume) ?

Check out the [original blog post](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/48706198060/how-to-analyze-twitter-data-with-hue) and the [Hadoop UI Hue](http://gethue.com) and it [Hadoop tutorials](http://hadoopexamples.com/).